# How to add a active class on ng-click buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is the html code for the buttons, `taskfilter` is the filter of how the buttons work on click and the class name is 'sel'

```
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 1" ng-class="{'sel':enabled}">
  <span>show completed</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 2" ng-class="{'sel':enabled}">
  <span>show to do</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilter = 0" ng-class="{'sel':enabled}">
  <span>show all</span>.
</a>
```

This is the code I used to add the class scope with the button on click removed the index in html because it wont work

```
$scope.taskfilters = 0;
$scope.taskfilter = function(index) {
    $scope.taskfilters = index;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilters = 1" ng-class="{'sel':taskfilters == 1}">
     <span>show completed</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilters = 2" ng-class="{'sel':taskfilters} == 2">
     <span>show to do</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-init="taskfilters = 0" ng-click="taskfilters = 0" ng-class="{'sel':taskfilters == 0}">
     <span>show all</span>.
</a>
```

Comment: but how do i have ' taskfilter = 0 button' with active class on inital value. it only shows no if i click on the button but i want to have the first button on reload with the class and if i click the other ones to have them red instead of the first button

Comment: Another option is, you can write $scope.taskfilters = 0 at very first line of controller to initialize value. Otherwise ng-init is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive

> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a `truthy` value the corresponding `key` is used as a `class name`.

```
<a ng-class="{'active' : taskfilter == 0}" ng-click="taskfilter = 0">
```

Comment: but how do i have ' taskfilter = 0 button' with active class on inital value.
it only shows no if i click on the button but i want to have the first button on reload with the class and if i click the other ones to have them red instead of the first button

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilters = 1" ng-class="{'sel':taskfilters == 1}">
     <span>show completed</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilters = 2" ng-class="{'sel':taskfilters} == 2">
     <span>show to do</span>.
</a>
<a class="clear-completed" ng-click="taskfilters = 0" ng-class="{'text-primary':!taskfilters, 'sel':taskfilters == 0}">
     <span>show all</span>.
</a>
```

Comment: i only need it to be orange on reload so you see that you are at the beginning, and if uou want to check the other ones the class switches to the other ones. if youo know this i wil make your answer the correct one

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

app.controller("con",function($scope) {

$scope.class = "red";
$scope.changeClass = function(){
if ($scope.class === "red")
  $scope.class = "blue";
else
  $scope.class = "red";
};
```

});

```
.red{
 color:red;
 }

  .blue{
  color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: <script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">      </script>
    <body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
    <div ng-class="class">{{class}}</div>
    <button ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>    
  </body>